# Add subscribe button to feed asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, rss

I have built an RSS feed and consume it in asp.net page.

In this page i want add a button that enables users to subsribe to the feed so that they stay updated with news(and informed).

If is that is not possible,should i work with a third party(feedblitz,...)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

you should use .ashx instead of .aspx pages as RSS data source.
Then Use

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="My Feed" href="RSSFeed.ashx" />
```

in head tag.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is just a link to the RSS that the user can open in their chosen reader and subscribe there.

If you add a link in the HTML  element then a RSS icon will appear in the location bar in the more modern browsers.

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="My Feed" href="feed.xml" />
```

Comment: the rss source is an asp.net page with code-behind generating xml(RSSFeed.aspx).I have added your Link Math,bu i see nothing.Thanks.